# How to set Windows 10 machine that is being used as a print server to set a lock screen 2 minutes after login

Tags: windows

I have a computer that is reserved as a print server. It’s a Windows 10 machine and has no other task other than print serving. It is active 24 hours a day.

Part of the process requires the computer being signed on as myself (the network administrator) and I need this computer to stay locked.

Everything I see in Windows 10 including registry tweaks are based upon locking the screen once the computer is inactive. But I need it to lock about 2 minutes after a sign in. Not just when the computer is inactive.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the Task Scheduler.

> Start -> Run -> taskschd.exe

Then create a new task that runs on account login under the account you will be using to login. Here's how:

1. **General tab**: Check run with with highest privileges.
2. **Triggers tab**: “New Trigger -> Begin the task -> At login.” Select the user or choose Any user.
3. Check Delay task for. You can type “2 minutes” into the dropdown.
4. Make sure it's enabled and hit OK.
5. **Actions tab**: New. Select “Start a program” and type in Program/script: `Rundll32.exe`
6. Add arguments: `user32.dll,LockWorkStation` then click OK
7. Uncheck everything in Conditions and Settings and hit OK.

You should now have a task that will run 2 minutes after login that will automatically lock the computer. For reference the command that does this is:

```
Rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

Comment: The task scheduler option works perfectly. I need this to be performed automatically and it does (now). This print server bridges two different systems. Thank You.